# Why does the Bug drink sugar water in MiB?

Tags: men-in-black

In Men in Black, after the bug steals Edgar's skin he comes in and asks his wife for
a glass of sugar water. **Why exactly does the bug need sugar water?** Is it for the bug to live or help a bodily function?

Comment: Bugs like sugar on our world too

Answer (score 31, accepted):

He was hungry and thirsty after his journey to Earth.

> Being folded into N-space was not only painful and irritating, it also
> made him hungry. The ship's replicator hadn't worked worth dung the
> last four cycles and he was starving when he ate the remains of the
> Edgar. Now, after such a hasty meal, he was thirsty. He needed a nice
> drink.
>
> <sub><sup>[Men in Black: A Novelization](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2365012.Men_in_Black)</sup></sub>

Comment: @user50780 - Sometimes [the answer just hits you in the face](https://media.giphy.com/media/3NgcLVc9B2tEPUUCMz/giphy.gif)

Answer (score 14):

Plants produce [nectar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nectar), which some insects consume. Beekeepers commonly take the honey away from their bee colonies and [replace it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beekeeping#Structure_of_a_bee_colony) with sugar water, too.

Comment: A Beekeeper may supplement a hive's food supply over the winter with some sugar water.  A good beekeeper only removes honey in excess of what the hive needs for food.  The best food for a hive is honey.  Bees will happily collect sugar water if it is available, as it is much easier to collect than nector.  However, it results in a poor quality, watered-down, honey production.